# Literature (PDF) management for institutes

Tags: collaboration, document-management

My institute is looking for a system to collaboratively manage literature on a server.

In the first place, we want to organize our electronic literature archive. These are almost exclusively PDF files. It would be interesting to include our stock of paper-based books as well, but if this isn't possible, it shouldn't be a problem. Probably closest would be a PDF management with a client-server architecture where people can upload their PDF files, search for what they need and download the PDF files they need. The problem is, a directory structure on a Windows server doesn't allow tagging and the searching/sorting abilities are limited. Also, we don't want to force everyone to use e.g. Endnote or Mendeley. So people should be able to import literature from the central repository into their own reference managers.

We have a userbase of about 35 users. Is there anything remotely close to the case I am describing here?

Comment: What does the library of your institution recommend?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a shopping question. [softwarerecs.se] can take this type of question, but please read their help centre and meta post on how to ask, first, to ensure your question can be edited to meet their standards.

Comment: How does the citation management part relate to the document management part? Are they tied together or two separate requirements?

Comment: There is a very [similar question on academia.stackexchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12728/literature-management-for-workgroups/13971) which may contain some helpful software suggestions.

Comment: My very own question might contain helpful links in the answers given http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2557/maintained-ubuntu-pdf-reader-with-text-highlighting

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend investigating running an instance of [Calibre Ebook manager](http://www.calibre-ebook.com/) in [server mode](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/cli/calibre-server.html) - this will allow you to search on things like tags - even to access the content on mobiles, provided that they have access to the server.  You can either leave uploading and tagging as restricted to those with direct access to the server or you can write/find/commission [plugins](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/creating_plugins.html) for one or both, *(Calibre plugins are written in python and stored in zip files)*.

Calibre is available for download for OS-X, Win32/64 and Linux plus as a portable app.  It is licenced as GNU GPL v3 so your usage should be no problem.

Note that Calibre also allows conversion between several ebook file formats.

Screenshot of accessing content on server via browser:
[image: In browser]
On IPhone
[image: On IPhone]

Comment: never knew  that u can run it on server

Comment: You can either start it from the GUI or with the command line calibre-server.

Comment: good to know! upvote from me :)