# PDF viewer with multiple groups of files in multiple windows

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, documentation-viewer

I have a problem viewing / searching of a multitude of PDF files, like absence of a viewer with multiple groups of files.

I usually use Foxit Reader, which is excellent; it can remember and reopen documents previously opened in tabs. I've asked them about a feature like this, but still no answer.

But I do need some viewer or editor which can open files in multiple windows, each with own set of files in tabs, loaded on demand in groups/sessions.

It would be great to have a solution multiplatform, like Windows (portable)/Linux.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for suggested edits, I like cleaner things.

Answer (score 2):

##### Edit/Update

**Mozilla Firefox Bookmarks:**
With the PDF file tabs open in the browser, create a new Bookmarks folder and add each file to it.
Create additional Bookmark folders for different PDF file groups, as needed.

To open multiple groups in multiple windows, start separate instances of Firefox and in each instance open the relevant Bookmark folder and select the option `Open All in Tabs`.
Tested with Firefox 98.0.2 on Win10x64.

**Note: My original suggestions here below did not meet the requirements.**
The Foxit "multiple instances" does not remember the PDF file group of each instance and the MS Edge Collections feature failed tests with local PDF files.

> **Not exactly what OP is looking for...** You are already on the right track with Foxit Reader.
> *(Note: this is based on Foxit Reader version 9.7.2)*
>
> Under the menu **File | Preferences | Documents** activate the setting
> `Allow multiple instances` in the *Open Settings* section. This will
> allow you to open several Foxit Reader windows, each with its own set
> of PDF documents.
>
> **This does not work with local PDFs...** Another (Windows) option that may work for you could be the "Collections" feature of MS Edge. Sorry,
> I don't have a suggestion for this use case under Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Bumpyride! I tried the option in my Foxit Reader version 10.1 during current session with a set of files. On opening new window this window shows the same set as been stored at last exit. This is probably because Foxit Reader stores session in windows registry.
I did ask Foxit about adding option of split set of files, preferably with saving session in a file, not registry but still no answer. May I am missing something. I believe the best option is some app that allows multiple portable instances with sessions in files.

Comment: Personally, I like Foxit Reader but I need multiple sessions.

Comment: @WebComer - You are right, Foxit does not remember the separate sessions. But...  I just managed to reproduce your exact requirements using Firefox bookmarks. I also found out (to my surprise) that the MS Edge Collections feature fails with local PDF files! I'll update my answer with the details.

Comment: Viewers like Foxit Reader allow for viewing or editing bookmarks, I'm not sure that there are browser's capabilities may be via plugins to allow that as well as searching across all tabs content.

Comment: I plan to add a list of PDF viewers to add to my question and check them out or may be someone could tell which one to choose.